# Getting ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32') while integrating API

Tags: python-3.x, api, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I had a perfectly working model that was able to predict ferilizer according to the temperature, humidity, soil type, soil pH, nitrogen, phosphorus and pottasium but the inputs like temperature and humidity were also input by the user.
I tried using an open weather API to get the values like temperature and humidity automatically without having the user input it.

But now i the results are not displayed and a value error for Nan is shown.
below is the code

```
import requests
import os
api_adress = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=*id from the site*&q='
city = input('Enter the city you are in')
url = api_adress + city
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
temp_data = float((json_data['main']['temp']) - 273.15)
hmdt = float(json_data['main']['humidity'])

print(temp_data,hmdt)
```

The result i'm getting from the above code is

```
Enter the city you are inkathmandu
28.0 51.0
```

so the api request is working

```
Soiltype = input('Enter the soil type:').lower()
Croptype = input('Enter the crop type:').lower()
Temperature = print('Temperature:', temp_data)
Humidity = print('Humidity:', hmdt)
Moisture = input('Enter moisture:')
potassium = input('Enter potasium:')
Phosphorous = input('Enter phosphorous:')
nitrogen = input('Enter nitrogen:')
result = model.predict([[Stype1, Ctype1, Temperature, Humidity, Moisture, potassium, Phosphorous, nitrogen]])
print(result)
```

the result is showing input contain NaN error. Could you please tell me why this is happening and how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Temperature = print('Temperature:', temp_data)
Humidity = print('Humidity:', hmdt)
```

Both these variables are assigned `None` value since `print()` returns `None`.

Comment: Ohh I get it. Thank you so much.